# upload image dataset to S3 sagemaker

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

my dataset is 3 folders (train, validation and test) of images. each folder has two subfolders (cat1 and cat2). I am using AWS sage maker to preprocess my data and train my model. we all know that we have to upload the training data to S3 bucket before starting the ".fit" process.
I want to know how to upload my data set to S3

```
# general prefix
prefix='chest-xray'
#unique train/test prefixes
train_prefix   = '{}/{}'.format(prefix, 'train')
val_prefix   = '{}/{}'.format(prefix, 'validation')
test_prefix    = '{}/{}'.format(prefix, 'test')

# uploading data to S3, and saving locations
train_path  = sagemaker_session.upload_data(train_data, bucket=bucket, key_prefix=train_prefix)
```

what the train_data parameters should look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/utility/session.html#sagemaker.session.Session.upload_data) `train_data` is the local path of the file to upload to S3, so you need this file locally where you are launching the training job. If you are using a notebook this is not the way to do. You have instead to manually upload your dataset in a S3 bucket. I suggest to preprocess your dataset in a single file (tfrecord for example if you are using TF) and upload that file to S3. You can do it using the AWS web console or using the AWS-CLI with the `aws s3 cp yourfile s3://your-bucket` command.